# Subjunctive Conditionals in the Past Tense

Tags: past-tense, conditionals, subjunctive-mood, irrealis-were

Is a sentence such as the one that follows grammatical and logical:

I was worried I would have lost a letter grade if I were to hand in the paper late.

I know the subjunctive, being a mood, can be transposed back and forth between tenses, and my guess is the above sentence works because the conditional refers, not to a past truth, but to a hypothetical within the past. Still, I’m not certain.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The subjunctive is a clause type, not a mood. There are no verbs in English that are inflected for mood.

Comment: I don't think I would necessarily say it's ungrammatical, but it would be far more common if it were rephrased slightly: *I was worried I would have lost a letter grade if I were to **have handed** in the paper late.* That maintains a parallel verb use between the first part of the sentence (*would have*) and the second part (*were to have*).

Comment: Would it be better to keep the entire conditional in the past indicative?

Comment: Or, alternatively, could it be a first conditional [present tense + future] backshifted into the past?